# Regex match until given text?

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a regular expression which will match `fooSVM??!`. I'd like to match `SVM` in this string, which means I need to match from `foo` until meet `?` or `!`. Note that `SVM` could be other Unicode characters.

I tried `foo(.*)[?!]*` but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: When you say "I'd like to match", do you mean retrieve? Or that `SVM` is the text matched by the regex?

Comment: @fge yes, I need to retrieve SVM

Answer (score 3):

Provided there cannot be newlines, this will do it:

```
foo([^?!]+)[?!]
```

and retrieve the first group.

```
foo        # Find "f", then "o", then "o",
(          # begin capture
    [^?!]  # followed by any character which is not "!" or "?",
    +      # once or more
)          # end capture
[?!]       # followed by either a "!" or a "?"
```

Comment: how could I not repeat the `?!` part, because I need to add characters in this filter list, so I'd like to keep it at one place

Comment: Well, if you are sure that at least one of these follows, just make do without the final character class (ie, `foo([^?!]+)`

Comment: You could use ungreedy matching, e.g. `foo(.*?)[?!]`, but note that the final character class can't get a `*` then.

Comment: @cbuckley why `.` when you can use a complemented character class ;) Lazy quantifiers are grossly overused imho

Comment: @fge I was being as lazy as my regex :) The negated character class is a definite winner.